# prove the angle of sum of vectors is always in the middle

Tags: geometry, vectors

For two planar vectors $v_1, v_2$, and they are in the same quadrant.

Define $\angle(v_1)$ as the angle between $v_1$ and positive x-axis. And $\angle{v_1} \lt \angle(v_2)$.

Their sum $v_3 = v_1+v_2$, would this be true $\angle(v_1) \lt \angle(v_3) \lt \angle(v_2)$? can you prove it?

Here is what I have tried:

It should be easy to see $v_3$ is in the same quadrant with $v_1, v_2$, since $v_3= (a_3, b_3)=(a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2)$, which $\forall a_i$ have the same sign and $\forall b_i$ have the same sign.

Since all $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are in the same quadrant, the angle between any two of them is less than 90. The three of them would form an acute triangle.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: thanks for your interest, i did try to draw them on paper, and nothing concrete comes to me :(  i think i only have the first step $v_3$ is also going to be in the same quadrant.

Comment: If the drawing of $v_1 + v_2$ and $v_2+v_1$ (both being equal of course) doesn't convince you and you want something more "coordinaty", try comparing the angle tangents $a_1/b_1$, $a_2/b_2$ and $a_3/b_3$ (without loss of generality you can consider all your vectors to be in the upper right quadrant).

Comment: I think I’m convinced, and I was looking for something concise and rigours

Comment: $v_3$ is along a diagonal of a parallelogram. You could rotate the parallelogram and based on your definition see that it might get values that are  no fitting you claim - unless the direction of the vectors have some limitations.

Comment: It's not true without further constraints: let e.g. $v_1=(2,0)$ and $v_2=(-1,0)$, then $0=\angle v_1=\angle v_3<\angle v_2=\pi$.

Comment: I think it’s been mentioned that $v_1,v_2$ are in the same quadrant, which your example violets

Answer (score 1):

Hint (elaborating on Tassle's comment):

You have that
$$\tan\angle v_1=\frac{a_1}{b_1},\ \tan\angle v_2=\frac{a_2}{b_2},\ \tan\angle v_3=\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}.$$
Since the $\tan$ function is monotonically increasing, it suffices to show that
$$\frac{a_1}{b_1}<\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}<\frac{a_2}{b_2}.$$
Since we know that $a_1/b_1<a_2/b_2$ (because $\angle v_1<\angle v_2$), can you prove the above inequality?